# New view from UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

So I've seen previous questions similar to this but they were of no help. I've read Apple's documentation too but I could not understand where I've gone wrong. AFAIK I did everything logically, but when I click on my done button on an UItoolbar overlay, the button can be pushed but it does not do anything. This obviously means it fails to acknowledge the written code. But how?

I want to bring up the .nib of "TableViewController" when a done button is clicked on my UIToolBar.  But the below isn't allowing the click to bring up a new view. How do I rectify this? Please show me where I went wrong and what should be replaced and why.

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed {

TableViewController *UIView = [[TableViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
UIView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:UIView animated:YES];
[UIView release];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, you've got some bizarre stuff going on here. In your first line, you're allocating and initiating the `TableViewController` instance correctly, but you're not giving that instance a unique name.  You're naming it with another class's name, which is bound to stir up problems.  In fact, I'm surprised it didn't through an error.

Try the following instead:

```
TableViewController *tableView = [[TableViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
tableView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:tableView animated:YES];
```

Now, your `TableViewController` instance has a unique name that is referenced throughout the rest of the method.  Just to be clear--`UIView` is another *class name*, and therefore cannot be used as the name of an instance of an object.

**EDIT:** Additionally, be sure to add your button's selector `doneButtonPressed:` to your .h file of its view controller. Also, if you like you can toss an `NSLog()` call in the beginning of the function just to be sure it isn't (or perhaps *is*) being called.

Comment: Naming conventions help avoid such mistakes and makes the code more readable.  Capitalised names mean types, such as classes, enums or typedefs, names starting with lower case are generally variables.  ALL_CAPITALS for #defines.

Comment: Still no luck guys. I've changed to exactly that, and I admit I made a mistake by naming the instance wrong, but it doesn't seem to be the root of the fault. I've changed it to what you guys have said, please look at my response to user490696 to see how I created the button. I don't think I made it wrong because the done button functions properly and performs an action like  this (entire code between quotes: "[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];", so it's the method I'm using that's wrong. If the line of code I mentioned worked obviously nothing is wrong with how I created the button?

Answer (score 0):

Something to check when button actions aren't firing is that you've got the appropriate selector.  If you've followed the selector correctly.  Make sure you aren't using a selector of

```
@selector(doneButtonPressed:)
```

which would look for a function like:-

```
- (void) doneButtonPressed:(id) sender
```

For your member function, you need

```
@selector (doneButtonPressed)
```

The debugger is your friend here.  Start with a breakpoint to make sure your function is being called.

If you're getting into the function, then The Kraken's answer is the next thing to check.

Comment: I used @selector(doneButtonPressed). It works properly, as I replaced everything within my - (void) doneButtonPressed {......} with     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; . when i click on the done button, it dismisses the current view controller normally. So it receives the action and acknowledges the code. It's just the method I wrote (see Kraken's code in his response) that doesn't function properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on using a class name as a variable name whatsoever.  Although you should change it because its confusing and doesnt follow iOS coding conventions.

"Button can be pushed but doesnt do anything", is the selector even being called?

-(void)doneButtonPressed

Show how you created the UIBarButtonItem to verify that you provided the right selector in the init method or that you connected the button directly in interface builder (which it doesnt look like since you didnt use the (IBAction) return signature.

Comment: I didn't use IB so i didn't have to use IBAction. My barbuttonitem was made programmatically .                                                   UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];

Comment: is the selector being called?

Comment: No it is not. Everything I put inside -(void)doneButtonPressed {..} is as good as putting nothing inside it. It just fails to recognize the code, it doesn't even crash when the button is pressed. The code I'm implementing in my doneButtonPressed is wrong. I've tested it with a different nib. It doesn't open that either when pressed. Any idea what the correct method is?