# Creating nib view from UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, overlay, uibarbuttonitem

So I've seen previous questions similar to this but they were of no help. I've read Apple's documentation too but I could not understand where I've gone wrong. AFAIK I did everything logically, but when I click on my done button on an `UIToolbar` overlay, the button can be pushed but it does not do anything. This obviously means it fails to acknowledge the written code. But how?

I want to bring up the .nib of "TableViewController" when a done button is clicked on my `UIToolbar`. But the below isn't allowing the click to bring up a new view. How do I rectify this? Please show me where I went wrong and what should be replaced and why.

```
//Here's the selector:
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:
    UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self  action:@selector(doneButtonPressed)];
```

Here's how I made my action.

```
-(void)doneButtonPressed {
    TableViewController *tableView = [[TableViewController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
    tableView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:tableView animated:YES];
}

// Yet nothing happens when I click on my done button on my overlay. The button
// can be clicked, but nothing happens. Please shed any insight pleasee!
```

Comment: You might want to diagnose whether the problem is the button or the method, so put a breakpoint (or NSLog) in `doneButtonPressed` and determine whether the method is being called and not doing what you expected or whether it's not being called at all. Then you can focus your diagnostic efforts in the right area. (BTW, I assume that both the initialization of the bar button and the `doneButtonPressed` method are in the view controller and not in some custom view class.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's being called, but as before there's no action.

Comment: Ok, if we know that `doneButtonPressed` is definitely called, all of the stuff about the bar button is irrelevant. Thing is, there's nothing strange about your `doneButtonPressed`. I assume you've started to put log statements/breakpoints in the `initWithNibName` (assuming you have one) and the `viewDidLoad` of your `TableViewController`? And you say "nothing happens", you don't see a blank table, but rather literally nothing happens at all, i.e. you see the same screen as you did before? At this point, if you want assistance, we might need to start to see relevant `TableViewController` code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New view from UIBarButtonItem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706862/new-view-from-uibarbuttonitem). also possibly duplicate of [Switching views from barbuttonitem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714090). When you want to make a correction to a question, edit it, don't ask another duplicative question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the UIToolbar into a nib file?

Comment: No it's an overlay for the UIIMagePickerController. I made it programmatically.